# Locked Controls during Special Process

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I wrote a function that download something like a pic from net , and use it
in a click event of special button.
my problem is when i click on button and the app start downloading pic from
internet , all of my controls in form , lock (until download process is done!)
not just only controls , all of my form too.
so how can i handle this process in background of application and the 
user can work with other control at Same time.

Comment: all you need is asynchronous programming

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is asynchronous programming

here is a very simple demo

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Text = "doing something...";
    var result = await SomeHeavyWork();
    this.Text = result.ToString();
}

private async Task<int> SomeHeavyWork()
{
    using (var hc = new HttpClient())
    {
        var data = await hc.GetAsync("www.google.com");
        return data.Content.Headers.Count();
    }
}
```

What's happening here?

1. when you click `button1`, `button1_Click` will execute.
2. it first set the form text to "doing something..."
3. it now waits for `SomeHeavyWork()` to complete its work.
4. we are now exiting `button1_Click` function and do what we were doing before clicking `button1`(running the form message loop). but somewhere else we execute `SomeHeavyWork()` and waiting for it.
5. when  `SomeHeavyWork()` job is finished we came back to `button1_Click` and execute the `this.Text = result.ToString();` line.

please read this [msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx)

Comment: tnx man , im going to read Asynchronous programming , its help me too much